# OpenCV HoughTransformation in Swift

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, opencv, hough-transform

I'm about to program a project in which I need to extract the straight lines out of an image. 
The first thing that came to my mind is Hough Transformation. So I downloaded the OpenCV framework, added it to my project. Added the Bridging Header as well as the OpenCVWrapper.h and the OpenCVWrapper.mm files. But I can't find any tutorial on how to implement the hough transformation into my swift project. So what sort of files do I need to create to write the function in? And how should that function look like?
I'm happy to hear any helpful suggestion!

Kind regards
Robert

Answer (score 0):

I'm also currently working on OpenCV with Swift, it indeed didn't have much tutorial about it.

About the Hound Transformation, here is the [link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a) to the documentation, hope it helps.

And [this project](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch) helps a lot when I want some reference.

Good luck!